# How to scrub VT100/ANSI control chars in Net::Telnet

Tags: ruby, telnet, control-characters, vt100

I am using `Net::Telnet` to connect to a HP ProCurve Switch to login and backup the config. However I ran into issues where `waitfor` returns VT100/ANSI control chars:

```
< 0x00000: ff fd 18 ff  fd 1f ff fb  01 1b 5b 32  4a 1b 5b 3f  ..........[2J.[?
< 0x00010: 37 6c 1b 5b  33 3b 32 33  72 1b 5b 3f  36 6c 1b 5b  7l.[3;23r.[?6l.[
< 0x00020: 31 3b 31 48  1b 5b 3f 32  35 6c 1b 5b  31 3b 31 48  1;1H.[?25l.[1;1H
< 0x00030: 48 50 20 4a  39 37 32 38  41 20 32 39  32 30 2d 34  HP J9728A 2920-4
< 0x00040: 38 47 20 53  77 69 74 63  68 0d 0d 0a  53 6f 66 74  8G Switch...Soft
< 0x00050: 77 61 72 65  20 72 65 76  69 73 69 6f  6e 20 57 42  ware revision WB
< 0x00060: 2e 31 35 2e  31 32 2e 30  30 31 35 0d  0d 0a 0d 0d  .15.12.0015.....
< 0x00070: 0a 43 6f 70  79 72 69 67  68 74 20 28  43 29 20 31  .Copyright (C) 1
< 0x00080: 39 39 31 2d  32 30 31 34  20 48 65 77  6c 65 74 74  991-2014 Hewlett
< 0x00090: 2d 50 61 63  6b 61 72 64  20 44 65 76  65 6c 6f 70  -Packard Develop
< 0x000a0: 6d 65 6e 74  20 43 6f 6d  70 61 6e 79  2c 20 4c 2e  ment Company, L.
< 0x000b0: 50 2e 0d 0a  0d 0a 20 20  20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20  P.....
```

Unfortunately, this screws up `waitfor` because if I try to `waitfor(/^password:/i)` it will return a string with those control chars in it, or wait forever since the regex is never matched.

Is there any way to have `Net::Telnet` automatically remove those control characters? Is there any way to have `waitfor` only care about ASCII printable characters?

Comment: Please read "[ask]", the linked pages, and "[mcve]". Please show us what you tried so we can help fix it, instead of having to write a tutorial along with sample code.

Comment: When talking to a device like that, you probably want to change its idea of what sort of device it's talking to. Tell it your session is a TTY and the control characters should go away. You probably also want to tell it to use the longest line-width possible, or to turn off automatic line-wraps if possible, as those will make it more difficult. [su] would probably be a good source of information.

Comment: @theTinMan Is there a way to do this in ruby's Net::Telnet? I didn't see an option to change to a TTY, and the device/devices I'm connecting to don't seem to have a way to turn the control chars off. This is also a Net::Telnet specific question, Super User probably would not have the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: This is usually done by issuing a command on the device, not in Net::Telnet. Telnet isn't a secure protocol so you probably should use the SSH version, but you'll tell need to change the terminal type from VT-something or XTerm or Linux or ... to TTY.

Comment: @theTinMan Yeah I was just hoping to not have to issue that command "blind", I manage a lot of devices and they all have different setting and levels of privileges (some need to be enabled, some need to have "configure", some require usernames and passes, some do not) and its really really frustrating to do all this blindly. There is a command I found after much digging to turn it off but the issue is that I already have to login and initiate everything without knowing exactly what's going on.

Comment: That's a two-fold problem. Your networking people need to standardize on configurations is the first and bigger problem because automation doesn't work well with non-standardized environments. I work with a huge number of networking devices and it took about five years to get the networking people to understand why standards are so important. It's possible to make the code resilient and able to sense an environment but you shouldn't have to do that too much.